# Java Generic - How do I combine static functions?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible in Java to combine these two static functions in the style of a C++ template parameter? I've tried passing in the class, but that just gives errors about not knowing what the type parameter is. Sorry, I've googled a good bit, but I'm new to Java and having a rough time figuring this one out.

```
import com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.BeanListProcessor;
import com.univocity.parsers.tsv.TsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.tsv.TsvParserSettings;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

public class Parsers {
    public static List<ThingOne> ParseThingOne(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        BeanListProcessor<ThingOne> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<ThingOne>(ThingOne.class);
        TsvParserSettings tsvSet = new TsvParserSettings();
        tsvSet.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
        tsvSet.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
        TsvParser p = new TsvParser(tsvSet);
        FileReader f = new FileReader(fName);
        p.parse(f);
        return rowProcessor.getBeans();
    }

    public static List<ThingTwo> ParseThingTwo(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        BeanListProcessor<ThingTwo> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<ThingTwo>(ThingTwo.class);
        TsvParserSettings tsvSet = new TsvParserSettings();
        tsvSet.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
        tsvSet.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
        TsvParser p = new TsvParser(tsvSet);
        FileReader f = new FileReader(fName);
        p.parse(f);
        return rowProcessor.getBeans();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are ThingOne and ThingTwo part of a class hierarchy?

Comment: Seems to me, ThingOne and ThingTwo need to share an interface or base class.   Then you should be able to combine the two methods based on that.

Comment: Basically I'm with tatmanblue here.  Java is different than C++ and not as flexible.  The standard approach here in Java would be to force ThingOne and ThingTwo to share a common interface (maybe `Parsable` or something) and then just return that super type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are saying passing class is not working for you. This should work:

```
List<ThingOne> l1 = parse(ThingOne.class, "file1");
List<ThingTwo> l2 = parse(ThingTwo.class, "file2");

public static <T> List<T> parse(Class<T> clazz, String fName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    BeanListProcessor<T> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<>(clazz);
    TsvParserSettings tsvSet = new TsvParserSettings();
    tsvSet.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    tsvSet.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
    TsvParser p = new TsvParser(tsvSet);
    FileReader f = new FileReader(fName);
    p.parse(f);        
    return rowProcessor.getBeans();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create an interface or class and make your two classes inherit/extend from it, you can use Java Generics. So for example, if you make an interface `MyInterface`, such that:
`ThingOne implements MyInterface` and `ThingTwo implements MyInterface`. Then you can write a generic function as following:

```
public static <T extends MyInterface> List<T> ParseThing(String fName, Class<T> clazz) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    BeanListProcessor<T> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<T>(clazz);
    TsvParserSettings tsvSet = new TsvParserSettings();
    tsvSet.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    tsvSet.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
    TsvParser p = new TsvParser(tsvSet);
    FileReader f = new FileReader(fName);
    p.parse(f);
    return rowProcessor.getBeans();
}
```

Comment: You can't do T.class here, ignore FundMapping and FundPrice, these should be thingOne and ThingTwo

Comment: Right, missed that one. Class needs to be passed as well. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> parseThing( final String fName, final BeanListProcessor<T> rowProcessor )
  throws FileNotFoundException
{
    final TsvParserSettings tsvSet = new TsvParserSettings();
    tsvSet.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    tsvSet.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
    final TsvParser p = new TsvParser(tsvSet);
    final FileReader f = new FileReader(fName);
    p.parse(f);
    return rowProcessor.getBeans();
}
```

Called by something like these:

```
parseThing( "filename1", new BeanListProcessor<ThingOne>(FundPrice.class));

parseThing( "filename2", new BeanListProcessor<ThingTwo>(FundMapping.class));
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, FundPrice and FundMapping are the real names, ThingOne and ThingTwo are things I made up to simplify the problem.

Comment: I do not like Java so far.